# Is it possible to manipulate a soap envelope element?

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, soapui

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="http://someuri/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
            <Element>
                ///
            </Element>
            <Element>
                ///
            </Element>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Hello

i need to change the uri in [xmlns:api="http://someuri/"] in the envelope element to "someotheruri" with a GroovyScript.

I searched for hours how to use xmlslurper, xmlparser and every node would be easily changeable. But i need to change this namespace that is in the rootelement.

```
def source = new File("test.xml").text

    def root = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(source)
    println(root.lookupNamespace("api"))
```

It give me the uri as a String but not the node of it. Do i missing something?

It is really late and now my last hope is to ask here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: i need to change a project in soapui pro with over 200 Testcases. The uri changed and i want to write a script so everytime the project thinks is good to change a uri i can write in the project propertys the new uri and done.

Because everytime to change all testcases manually is exhausting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project file is an XML. You can do a `replaceAll()` on the project file outside of SoapUI:

```
def projectFileA = new File('/path/to/your/soapui-project.xml')
def projectFileB = projectFileA.text.replaceAll('xmlns:api="http://someuri/"', 'xmlns:api="http://someotheruri/"')
projectfileA.text = projectfileB
```

Comment: Thats really helpful. I complete forgot that soapui projects are only big xml files. The code works and do what i need. It is a good solution.

Comment: But i'm curious is it not possible to change somthing in the envelope element itself?
I stumbled over a "Solution" from SmartBear

`request.namespaces["api"] = context.expand('${#Project#newapi}')`

but that was not was i expected. Still learning how Groovy and SoapUi interact.